# How many different werewolf variants are there?

Tags: mythical-creatures, werewolves

I know there are different types of lycanthrope, a shapeshifter with 2 shifts. I know that different cultures (like japanese, western, norse) discuss the consent of lycanthropes. But how many different types of shifters in these stories are lycanthrope?

Comment: Your question is vague.  Do you mean "human who becomes a wolf"?  Or something more specific?  (The answer to the first is that they are legion.)

Answer (score 3):

Werewolves are an individual race, though the word "werewolf" is used as a descriptive word to describe any similar creature race.

Varcolac - A Romanian creature that is commonly believed to be a wizard who can take a wolf's form.

Loup-garou - A creature native to France that shares a lot of similarities with Werewolves.

Lupo-mannero - Italian creatures similar to Loup-garou

Benandanti - Werewolf-like creatures also from Italy that can leave their physical body and travel to Hell

Varulv - Norwegian creatures that can change into the form of a wolf by wearing a certain kind of clothing, usually a belt

Lubins - Fairy-like creatures from Brittany that like to shapeshift into wolf form

Lob-hombre - Spanish wolf-like shapeshifter that prefers gemstones to human flesh

Volkolak - Russian shapeshifters that can transform into a wolf or a bear